# Should microformats be used over the <address> tag?

Tags: semantics, addresses, mircoformat

I have been working on a webpage that contains many mailing addresses contained in `<address>` tags. Currently I have been looking into using microformats to "enrich" the present addresses contained on my webpage.

While researching I have read microformats are not uniformly supported by browsers, and draw unwanted attention to your data (data mining). I also noticed microformats add a lot of "beef" to code and many of my internal content editors may not find it so easy to grasp.

Should microformats be used over the `<address>` tag? Do microformats provide a better user experience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<address>` tag is intended to be used for contact information for the author of the nearest `<article>` or `<body>` ancestor. Using it to indicate contact information for multiple entities or even a single entity that is not the author of the page is confusing the semantics of the element. This is why we have the microformat hCard.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/address

Additionally, I would argue the hCard CAN provide a better UX than `<address>`. Most browsers have plugins, or native functionality that can detect microformats on a page and allow you to do various things such as import them into your address book or download a vCard.

See http://microformats.org/wiki/browsers

These functions are not provided with `<address>`. Arguably, this could not be of much benefit depending on if your user-base would install a plugin for using microformats.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i'm aware the `<address>` tag and any address microformats have no user-visible implications, which makes this not really a UX issue at all: Its only relevance is to search engines or other crawlers.

google and bing (via schema.org) recommend the [ContactPoint schema](http://schema.org/ContactPoint).  If you want your data indexed, use that.  If you don't want your data indexed, it doesn't really matter what you do.

Comment: ..though it does affect the user's experience who is looking for the information through a search engine.  Google maps locations and enhances search results based on structured data.

Comment: I would like to improve the search results but I was just curious if mircoformats were worth their trouble. I looking for an answer that won't just benefit the user but benefit our editors as well. Editors have a different type of experience and that's maintaining the code.